# Clearing/Un-selecting Radio button on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a LOT of radio buttons on a form I'm creating.

The reason why I am using radio buttons and not check box's is because I only want to let a user select one or none.

The bad thing about a radio button though is, once selected, it can't be undone. I am trying to add the feature of clearing a group of radio box's when it's clicked for the second time.

My method that I am implementing now works if I have a group of radio buttons I want to target individually but not if I want to implement it for ALL radio button groups on the page.

When I use multiple radio button groups, it will randomly un-select a radio button when I try to select a different option.

If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

**[JSFIDDLE for only one group of radio buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/BtLxY/) (works)**

*If you change to this code instead and target an individual name, it works.*

```
$('input[name="rad"]').click(function()
```

**[JSFIDDLE for multiple groups of radio buttons](http://jsfiddle.net/BtLxY/12/) (doesn't work)**

*I am trying to be able to target all my radio button groups at once, because there are a LOT.*

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var $radio = $(this);

        // if this was previously checked
        if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
        {
            $radio.prop('checked', false);
            $radio.data('waschecked', false);
        }
        else
            $radio.data('waschecked', true);

        // remove was checked from other radios
        $radio.siblings('input[name="rad"]').data('waschecked', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: You want the user to be able to select one or none, use a checkbox. Disable the other checkboxes when you check one, and enable them when you uncheck.

Comment: And if they choose 2? @tymeJV

Comment: When listening to Radio buttons you need to listen for a `change` event because `click` is inconsistent at best across the web browser spectrum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you just need a way to check/uncheck reliably by `name` groups.

Something like this should work:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click change', function () {//on click/change    
    $(this).prop('checked')//if checked
    ? $(this).prop('checked',false).data('waschecked', false)//uncheck
    : $(this).prop('checked',true).data('waschecked', true)//else check
    .siblings('input[name="'+$(this).prop('name')+'"]').data('waschecked', false);//make siblings false
});
```

kept the `.data('waschecked', ...)` in case you needed to have that value, but it works without it like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click change', function () {//on click/change    
    $(this).prop('checked')//if checked
    ? $(this).prop('checked',false)//uncheck
    : $(this).prop('checked',true);//else check
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/ZUb65/

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. Should this work on most browsers?

Comment: **Indeed it should.** If you find one that it doesn't work in, then let me know and I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the line to use the name attribute of the clicked radio in the selector expression

```
$radio.siblings('input[name='+ $(this).attr('name') +']').data('waschecked', false);
```

You just need to clear your "waschecked" flag on the other radios of the same group.

http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/BtLxY/15/

And just in case you do need to target using onchange: http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/BtLxY/27/

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
    var $radio = $(this);

    // if this was previously checked
    if ($radio.data('waschecked') == true)
    {
        $radio.prop('checked', false);
        $radio.data('waschecked', false);
    }
    else
        $radio.data('waschecked', true);

    // remove was checked from other radios
    $radio.siblings('input[name='+ $(this).attr('name') +']').data('waschecked', false);
});
```

Comment: Hey Jammy, this works perfectly in the jsfiddle. But for some reason not working to hot on my website. Not sure why. It may have to do with me using custom images as my selected radio button. I'll have to take a look. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a simple primary to secondary relationship then try this out:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="main_radios"]').on('change', function(){

    $('input[type="radio"][name="secondary_radios"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[type="radio"][name="third_radios"]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[type="radio"][name="fourth_radios"]').prop('checked', false);

    // combine it all into one call if you really feel like it
    $('input[type="radio"][name="secondary_radios"], input[type="radio"][name="third_radios"], input[type="radio"][name="fourth_radios"]').prop('checked', false);

});
```

Uncheck all radios that are not "this" name

```
// Listen for ANY radio to be changed
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){

    // remember name of selected radio
    var checked_name = $(this).attr('name');

    // target only radios that are not "this" name and uncheck them
    $('input[type="radio"]').filter(function(){
        if($(this).attr('name') != checked_name){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }).prop('checked', false);

});
```

Comment: Let's just say I have 100 different groups of radio buttons. Not sure I want to make a new function for every 100 buttons.